# Memory mapping, virtual and physical memory in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-mapping

I am trying to solve the following issue: having a custom data container that manages a generic type, I need to allow for other application components to retrieve the container's internal pointer and use it as if it were a simple `T*` array region (without treating it as a more intelligent array holder). The problem is that this memory is, in a very special case, moved somewhere else and erased. So there are a plethora of components that are aware of the old data pointer and will use that one to access their required information.

The setup looks, pseudo-codeish, something like this:

```
container<T>
{ 
  T* ptr;
  public:
  ContainerInterfaceCode..
}
```

**Hypothesis:**

`T* ptr` is a pseudo-address (may I call it "virtual"?) which is mapped in a physical space A.

When an event is risen, `T* ptr`'s mapping will be set for another physical space, B.

Any component that uses `T* ptr` is then oblivious of the change of physical location, "thinking" its data is stored at that virtual address.

**Conclusion:**

I would therefore like to know *whether there is a mechanism involving memory mapping (virtual to physical) that will allow to juggle with the mapping of the `T* ptr`*, thus leaving other application components untouched. Simply put, `T* ptr` should point to a memory region that gets mapped in a certain part, and, upon request, that same pointer will be mapped in another place (where the underlying data is to be copied for consistency). This must allow seamless transitions.

Note: I can't use wrappers, smart pointers, handles, etc. for the simple fact that it means modifying a huge codebase just for one, rather minor, modification.

As I haven't found enough resources dealing with this scenario, can anyone, perhaps, present a short webography with some relevant reading material on the subject?

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question, but I want to say no this is not possible.

Comment: I'll edit the question with a small "figure"

Comment: mechanism involving memory mapping (virtual to physical)?

Comment: @HAL: the function `OSMapMemory()` mentioned in this thread http://osdir.com/ml/linux.drivers.modem.hcf/2002-07/msg00005.html sounded like a potential solution for my hypothesized scenario. That's why I got the feeling such a thing is valid and can be implemented in C++.. but I have no other lead.

Comment: @teodron It is possible to have two different virtual addresses refer to the same physical memory.  Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

In linux you can used the shared memory.The shared memory is a mechanism which allow two process  access a same area of memory, it is a kind of IPC method. You can find some more 
details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory.

Comment: For the case of multiple processes (I have used shared memory for IPC instead of sockets since it was faster), this is a solution. I have one process with multiple components (so, basically, same address space).. hence your solution might not work (as it doesn't really leave the data pointer itself unchanged).

Comment: As you have multiple components, so if you want to use the shared memory you should manage the memory by yourself, such as create a array or other structure and you must use the semaphore to protect the  memory to avoid 2 processes write it in one time. Another even the shared memory is faster than socket, but it is more difficult to  handle, I prefer to do it with the socket because it is more stable and easy to use.

Comment: doing that is impossible without some kind of a handle/smart pointer and a specialized manager/observer to keep track of all pointers that point to the same memory as my container's `T* ptr`. Such a mechanism is _way_ too complicated and demands a lot of attention to detail and know-how. I was hoping to avoid it since it also means incurring massive changes to a huge code-base that needs to be maintained every day.

Comment: In my previous project, we created a rb-tree in the shared memory to manage the memory, and we use serval semaphores to protect it from multiple writing.